# Combine two monads when neither has a transformer?

Tags: haskell, monads, monad-transformers

I'm playing around with writing a web app. In this case, I'm using [scotty](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/scotty-0.0.1) and [redis](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hedis-0.3.1), but this problem comes up in any web/db combo. I used happstack before this, so I'd love an example there too.

Scotty has you define routes in a nested monad, which makes it easy to access the database connection within a route:

```
main = do
    db <- connect defaultConnectInfo
    scotty 3000 $ do

    get "/keys" $ do
        keys <- liftIO $ runRedis db $ keys "*"
        html $ T.pack $ show keys
```

The do block in get has type: `Web.Scotty.ActionM ()`. All the redis commands have type `Database.Redis.Redis a`. Neither redis or scotty has a monad transformer.

What's the best way to combine these? I'm new to haskell, but I did manage to get ReaderT working with the web monad in happstack.

Ideally, I could somehow make a new monad stack that supports both `keys` and `html` in the same do block.

Comment: Do people normally just settle for liftIO in haskell web frameworks?

Comment: I don't know an answer here, but I figure your problem is similar to monad transformers.  Basically, you want to implement a type, let's call it `IdentityTT m' m a`, such that `IdentityTT m'` behaves exactly like [`IdentityT`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/transformers/0.2.1.0/doc/html/Control-Monad-Trans-Identity.html).  The first question to be answered, of course, is if that's even possible.

Comment: Another way to phrase the question is: Do you use liftIO to query a database in all haskell frameworks? What the most common pattern when the database isn't baked into the framework?

Comment: I don't see the problem with liftIO here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For some reason I felt like liftIO was ugly, but it's really not bad. Especially if you do this:

```
queryRedis :: Connection -> Redis a -> ActionM a
queryRedis db r = liftIO $ runRedis db r
```

And define a partially applied function `redis = queryRedis db`. Thanks everyone